# Converting an options array into a variants array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, e-commerce

I am playing around with creating e-commerce dashboard. A part of the dashboard is for the user to be able to create variants of a product. So this is my thinking so far:

```
const options = [
  {
    display_name: "Colour",
    _id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4a2",
    option_values: [
      {
        _id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1198",
        label: "Red"
      },
      {
        _id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1197",
        label: "Green"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    display_name: "Size",
    _id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4a3",
    option_values: [
      {
        _id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1199",
        label: "Small"
      },
      {
        _id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1121",
        label: "Medium"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    display_name: "Weight",
    _id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4g3",
    option_values: [
      {
        _id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1122",
        label": "10"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The user ends up creating an array of 3 objects: Colour, Size, Weight. Within each object is a nested array which contains the option_values. This consists of for example "Red" and "Green".

Now for this to work correctly I need to take this options array and convert it into a variants array like this:

```
const variants = [
  {
    price: 0,
    sku: "RED-SMALL-10",
    option_values: [
      {
        option_id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1198",
        id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4a2"
      },
      {
        option_id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1199",
        id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4a3"
      },
      {
        option_id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1122",
        id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4g3"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    price: 0,
    sku: "RED-MEDIUM-10",
    option_values: [
      {
        option_id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1198",
        id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4a2"
      },
      {
        option_id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1121",
        id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4a3"
      },
      {
        option_id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1122",
        id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4g3"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    price: 0,
    sku: "GREEN-SMALL-10",
    option_values: [
      {
        option_id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1197",
        id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4a2"
      },
      {
        option_id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1199",
        id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4a3"
      },
      {
        option_id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1122",
        id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4g3"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    price: 0,
    sku: "GREEN-SMALL-10",
    option_values: [
      {
        option_id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1197",
        id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4a2"
      },
      {
        option_id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1121",
        id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4a3"
      },
      {
        option_id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1122",
        id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4g3"
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

With this array, the user will be able to see a variant which consists of:

```
Red - Small - 10
Red - Medium - 10
Green - Small - 10
Green - Medium - 10
```

As you can imagine, the user is able to add an extra weight if they wish, so it could look like this:

```
Red - Small - 10
Red - Small - 12
Red - Medium - 10
Red - Medium - 12
Green - Small - 10
Green - Small - 12
Green - Medium - 10
Green - Medium - 12
```

The issue I am having is converting the options array into the variants array. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) first build possible combination `sets` by going over options.

2) build `idObj` with keys as values as `_id`.

3) Go over possible `sets` from step 1 and build each object in required form.

```js
const variants = options => {
  let sets = [[]];
  const id_obj = {};
  options.forEach(option => {
    const new_sets = [];
    option.option_values.forEach(({ label, _id }) => {
      new_sets.push(Array.from(sets, set => [...set, label]));
      id_obj[label] = { id: option._id, value_id: _id };
    });
    sets = new_sets.flatMap(set => set);
  });

  return sets.map(set => ({
    price: 0,
    sku: set.join("-").toUpperCase(),
    option_values: set.map(label => ({ option_id: id_obj[label].value_id, id: id_obj[label].id }))
  }));
};

const options = [
  {
    display_name: "Colour",
    _id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4a2",
    option_values: [
      {
        _id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1198",
        label: "Red"
      },
      {
        _id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1197",
        label: "Green"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    display_name: "Size",
    _id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4a3",
    option_values: [
      {
        _id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1199",
        label: "Small"
      },
      {
        _id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1121",
        label: "Medium"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    display_name: "Weight",
    _id: "5e70047aa2f3c2574a27e4g3",
    option_values: [
      {
        _id: "5e736980646ed90f741f1122",
        label: "10"
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(variants(options));
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so so much

Comment: I have a slight problem. In the result (variant array) I need to replace the label property with the option_values id property. I managed to get it to work, but as you can imagine the SKU now contains only IDs

Comment: I have updated the original example. I hope it makes sense

Comment: @Richy, Yeah, that make sense. I also updated the answer.